# How to check the values of several columns in excel return the value of greatest occurance

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Assuming I have these following status:

```
0-Not started
1-In progress
2-With issue
3-Completed
4-N/A
```

And I have these following data:

```
Status A     Status B     Status C     Overall Status
-----------  -----------  -----------  -------------- 
Not started  Not started  In progress  In progress
Completed    Completed    Completed    Completed
In progress  Completed    Completed    In progress
Completed    N/A          Completed    Completed
```

I want to display in Overall Status column with these conditions:

- If any of the status in A, B, C is "In progress" then, display "In progress"
- If all status in A, B, C are the same, then display whatever status is in A
- Ignore any status = "N/A"

How would I write an IF Statement in Excel?

Comment: what do you want to get in situations not covered in your description (e.g. one "with issue" and two "completed")? Do you just want the earliest status?

Comment: What if you have 1 Completed and 2 N/A, what should be the output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your objective is, since it is a bit unclear as pointed out in the comments by @pat2015 and @Máté Juhász

But it seems to me that the following formula would cover what you want to accomplish:

```
=IF(OR(A2="In progress",B2="In Progress",C2="In Progress"),"In Progress",IF(AND(OR(A2="Completed",A2="N/A"),OR(B2="Completed",B2="N/A"),OR(C2="Completed",C2="N/A")),A2,""))
```

If it finds **In Progress** in and of the three columns it'll say **In Progress.** Otherwise, it will see if all cells are **Completed** or **N/A** it will bring back the value of column A. (which - I guess - will be **Completed**.)